# kernel-devel version different from kernel on centos7

Tags: anaconda, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to install virtualbox on centos7 which requires kernel-devel package.

The problem is when I do `uname -r` I see `3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64` but yum by default installs `kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64`
I tried installing specific version by using commands

```
yum install "kernel-devel-$(uname -r)"
```

and

```
yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

but both fail with

```
No package kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 available.
```

and

```
No package kernel-devel-uname-r == 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 available.
```

resp.

On further digging, I found that I have two kernels installed.

```
$ yum list installed | grep kernel
kernel.x86_64                    3.10.0-957.el7                     @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                    3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7               @updates
kernel-debug-devel.x86_64        3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7               @updates
kernel-devel.x86_64              3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7               @updates
kernel-headers.x86_64            3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7               @updates
kernel-tools.x86_64              3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7               @updates
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64         3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7               @updates
```

Looks like for some reason anaconda is screwing up my system.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

and

why is anaconda screwing up my system ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved this by installing

`yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers`

and other dependencies for virtualbox like perl make gcc bzip2

And then I did

```
yum update
reboot
```

And after rebooting all worked perfectly and i could install virtualBox,
let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact same question as you, and I solved it with steps below:

1. download the rpm file of your kernel-devel and kernel-headers in `https://rpm.pbone.net/`
2. uninstall the existed kernel-devel and kernel-headers by `yum remove kernel-devel-xxx` and `yum remove kernel-header-xxxx`
3. install the kernel-devel and kernel-headers by command `rpm -i xxxxx.rpm`